# Fix length number in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to have a field in a Mysql table, which should accept inputs having a fixed size - no more, no less. The input data is a number, but solutions for strings can also be considered, as I have no problem storing this data as varchar like stuff.

To be exact, I want a datatype which will NOT allow me to store a number which is having less than 7 or greater than 7 digits. I dont want to use triggers/stored procedures.

Comment: Do client/Server side validation

Answer (score 0):

This may be possible with a stored procedure, but I wouldn't do this on database level. Validation like this belongs in your application.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is any way to achieve this in MySQL at present without using triggers or stored procedures. If MySQL supported [check constraints](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Check_constraint) then you could do it, but it doesn't, so you can't.

Answer (score 0):

The possible solutions are:

- TRIGGER on update/insert.
- CHECK constraint, but MySQL parses and promptly discards check constraints.
- Application-level validation.
- Foreign key to a lookup table containing the 900,000 integers of 7 digits.

The only other suggestion is to migrate to a SQL database that supports CHECK constraints.

Open-source databases that support CHECK constraints include:

- PostgreSQL
- SQLite
- Firebird
- Apache Derby
- HyperSQL

Every commercial database also supports CHECK constraints.

Basically, MySQL is the only SQL database on the market that *doesn't* support CHECK constraints!

Comment: "Foreign key to a lookup table containing the 900,000 integers of 7 digits." Also known as the "comedy option".

Comment: @Hammerite: Hey, there's always a solution to a given problem with a given set of constraints.  You might not like the cost tradeoff, but it would work!  :)

Comment: Seems like I will have to migrate to some other database server :(